# MySQL Order by two different fields at same time

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to display items from my database, here's an example

`user | 123 | abc
 Jack |  0  | b 
 John |  0  | c 
 Doe  |  1  | a`

and how I want it displayed on site is something like this

`user | 123 | abc
 Doe  |  1  | a 
 Jack |  0  | b 
 John |  0  | c`

I want it orderying by `abc`(abc=1) AND `123` (cat **then** dog **then** chicken)

Tips:

**abc** being either **0** or **1**

**123** being multiple things like: **chicken**, **dog**, **cat** etc..

The field isn't named 123 it's just an example and this is the query i'm using right now: SELECT * FROM users order by paid=1, animal='cat', animal='dog' It's bringing paid users up first but isn't ordering by animal

Comment: So what's not working about your `ORDER BY` clause at the moment?

Comment: Your explanation and data seem to be coming from different planets.  Is `123` (a *horrible* name for a column) a number or a string?

Comment: The tips don't clarify anything for me - if column 123 contains values like chicken or cat or dog why not show it in your example and how can column abc contain 0 or 1 ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff
The field isn't named 123 it's just an example and this is the query i'm using right now: 
`SELECT * FROM users order by paid=1 order by animal='cat', animal='dog'`

It's bringing paid users up first but isn't ordering by animal

Comment: Why does chicken come after dog ?

Comment: @P.Salmon this is just the way how it is in the database and how the I'm looking to do it, I know it's a little bit annoying

Comment: In that case you may need a case statement to force the ordering

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table users;
create table users (name varchar(5),animal varchar(10),paid int);
insert into users values
('abc','dog',1),
('def','dog',0),
('ghi','chicken',0),
('jkl','cat',0);

select * from users 
order by paid desc,
        case 
            when animal = 'cat' then 1
            when animal = 'dog' then 2
            when animal = 'chicken' then 3
        end
```

result

```
+------+---------+------+
| name | animal  | paid |
+------+---------+------+
| abc  | dog     |    1 |
| jkl  | cat     |    0 |
| def  | dog     |    0 |
| ghi  | chicken |    0 |
+------+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the documentation:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
ORDER BY key_part1,key_part2,... ;
```

For more complex ordering, see here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
ORDER BY abc, 123
```

You don't need to write ASC in your case since ASC is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ~ORDER BY 123 DESC and abc ASC`

replace `test` with your table name.

```
select t.user,t.123,t.abc from test t order by t.123 DESC,t.abc ASC
```

[**Demo SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3af69/1)

<kbd>Output</kbd>

```
user    123     abc
Doe     1        a
Jack    0        b
John    0        c
```

Answer (score 0):

select a.user,a.123,a.abc from test a order by a.123 DESC,a.abc ASC